# XCode framework/library development workflow

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos

I'm new to OSX/iOS development and I'm developing a library project (Cocoa Touch Framework) for iOS. While working on the library I would like to test changes to the code, but because it's a library, I can't run it straight away from XCode and view it's output. What I'm used to do in other platforms, (Windows for example) is to create a another project under the same solution (Visual Studio), add the library to this project and write my test code there. Unfortunately I didn't find a way to do something similar in XCode, my workflow now consists of quitting/opening two different projects, copying frameworks around and re-adding framework dependencies.

Surely there must be a better way to do this...

Comment: I am not 100% sure but I think you could use Xcode`s workspace (something like solution in VS). Use your framework in another project in scope of one workspace - it makes cocoapods this way and I think this is how you want to use it.

Comment: Unit testing is the best choice for libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of post already in the SO .

But keeping it simple just follow these steps :

### 1.) Drag and drop Xcode project to your Xcode project 2.) go to build phase and then select your project (which u have imported ) to target. 3.) Search path - > user header search path (select your library) and also enter other linker flag.

Simple !

Comment: I didn't have to do the last part with adding the compiler flags but the rest of the steps solved my problem! (XCode 7.2)

Comment: yea last one is optional one .

Answer (score 0):

Is't exactly the same in Xcode :)

If you have a project (without  a test  build accompanying it) is:

1) See, no test Target :(

[image]

2) Click on the target that you want a test environment for (in my case, `locates`) so it's highlighted.
3) Click on the "edit" menu, then pop down to "Conver to" then "XCTest"

[image]

(yet another one of Apple's ambiguous places to hide things!)

Follow the wizard and that'll create you an XCTest build target that can be run on demand and through CI.

Have fun!

Comment: In the second step in the wizard when it prompts me to select a target, there are no targets.

Comment: You need to first create your target project (target) i.e. the app you want to write. As good measure I usually build it at least once (Command + Shift +B) If that doesn't work, and it still says the same, holler again and I'll post some more screenshot-throughs around various Xcode pitfalls :) - Happy swifting!

Comment: I have a library type project, and it builds ok. By the way I'm using Objective-C not Swift if that matters.

Comment: Doesn't matter at all. They're pretty much compatible with one another. If you're starting out, I'd advise reading though: "Swift 2.1 - https://itun.es/gb/jEUH0.l" Thats Bt apple themselves, and on top of that, if you come from a C, C++ or C# etc... background then I'd strongly suggest reading "Using Swift with Cocoa and Obj-C" - https://itun.es/gb/1u3-0.l (also by apple).. They'r their main "bibles"

Comment: If you come from a development background, you'd pay through a lot of those books easily. Theres'a  few  odd concepts thats take a while to get your head around.

Comment: I'm coming from a background of C, C++, C#, Java and some minor experience with other languages too. I learned both Swift and Objective-C, but it looks like for this project I'll have to use Objective-C. I read this document: pierre.chachatelier.fr/programmation/fichiers/cpp-objc-en.pdf which was very informative and convenient, and I learned Swift from Apple's documentation. I got most of the concepts of both languages, but XCode and iOS/OSX is still a bit unknown.

Comment: Coming from Java too will be REALLy handy when it comes to swift.. I see loads of things which are pretty similar in syntax (and this is me having come from Java over 10 years ago!). Don't ever forget that Obj-C is the underlying framework for Mac's.. Swift is just a Api that was slapped over it :D (Well more than that as it brings loads to the table)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100584/discussion-between-untrade-and-adrian-sluyters).